# Preview SVG using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg, preview

Is there an easy way to render SVG inside a page using javascript? What I want to do is set up a big textarea where a user can type SVG and click a button that renders it on the page.

Answer (score 6):

You can use DOM to create an [SVG element in your HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SVG_In_HTML_Introduction).

Answer (score 1):

A code sample (typed, not verified):

```
<textarea id="input"></textarea>
<button onclick="fPreview()">preview</button>
<div id="output"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function fPreview() {
    var oInput = document.getElementById("input");
    var oOutput = document.getElementById("output");
    // clean preview area
    if (oOutput.firstChild)
        oOutput.removeChild(oOutput.firstChild);
    // parse text into DOM and show it in preview
    var oSVGInput = new DOMParser().parseFromString(oInput.value, "text/xml");
    if (oSVGInput.documentElement)
        oOutput.appendChild(document.importNode(oSVGInput.documentElement));
    else
        oOutput.appendChild("Unknown error");
}
</script>
```

Comment: document.importNode(oSVGInput.documentElement) should be document.importNode(oSVGInput.documentElement, true) , else an parse error is thrown.